# SQL error for "node.entity_id" when using Linkit AJAX query

Tags: nodes

I use Linkit module in the CKEditor interface when editing content. But a SQL error happens when Linkit module executes a query to retrieve content:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'node.entity_id' in 'where clause': SELECT DISTINCT
>   field_data_title_field0.entity_type AS entity_type,
>   field_data_title_field0.entity_id AS entity_id,
>   field_data_title_field0.revision_id AS revision_id,
>   field_data_title_field0.bundle AS bundle FROM {field_data_title_field}
>   field_data_title_field0 INNER JOIN {node} node ON node.nid =
>   field_data_title_field0.entity_id WHERE
>   (field_data_title_field0.title_field_value LIKE
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\') AND
>   (field_data_title_field0.deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND
>   (node.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (node.type IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_3, :db_condition_placeholder_4,
>   :db_condition_placeholder_5)) AND (field_data_title_field0.entity_type
>   = :db_condition_placeholder_6) AND(( ( EXISTS (SELECT na.nid AS nid FROM {node_access} na WHERE (( (na.gid = :db_condition_placeholder_7)
>   AND (na.realm = :db_condition_placeholder_8) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_9) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_10) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_11) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_12) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_13) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_14) ))AND (na.grant_view >=
>   :db_condition_placeholder_15) AND (node.entity_id = na.nid) )) AND
>   (node.entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_16) )OR
>   (node.entity_type <> :db_condition_placeholder_17) )AND ( EXISTS
>   (SELECT na.nid AS nid FROM {node_access} na WHERE (( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_18) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_19) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_20) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_21) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_22) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_23) )OR( (na.gid =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_24) AND (na.realm =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_25) ))AND (na.grant_view >=
>   :db_condition_placeholder_26) AND (node.nid = na.nid) )) ORDER BY
>   node.title ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => %preva%
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => analysis
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_4] => og_basic_page
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_5] => subsite_og
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_6] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_7] =>
>   0 [:db_condition_placeholder_8] => all [:db_condition_placeholder_9]
>   => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_10] => nodeaccess_rid [:db_condition_placeholder_11] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_12] =>
>   nodeaccess_uid [:db_condition_placeholder_13] => 0
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_14] => nodeaccess_author
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_15] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_16] =>
>   node [:db_condition_placeholder_17] => node
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_18] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_19] =>
>   all [:db_condition_placeholder_20] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_21]
>   => nodeaccess_rid [:db_condition_placeholder_22] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_23] => nodeaccess_uid
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_24] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_25] =>
>   nodeaccess_author [:db_condition_placeholder_26] => 1 ) in
>   field_sql_storage_field_storage_query()

Query is faulty when retrieving nodes whose content type uses the "title" field (from module "title") instead of "title" core attribute. It concerns the SQL segment where DRUPAL queries node_access table. If I use my admin account, which has "Bypass content access control" permission, error doesn't appear.
I found some posts where they suspect OG is responsible, but if I inactivate OG on my site it doesn't solve the problem.
Any help will be welcome.
Best regards,
Pierre

Comment: Which version of Drupal is this? 7?

Comment: It is version 7